# Can I add a property dynamically in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Is it okay to add properties to an object at runtime? It seems to run okay but are there any issues I should be aware of?

I'm using a 3rd party javascript API which has an object class, which I've instantiated and added my own property to after instantiation,  like the code below:

For example can I do this:

```
var Car = function (id, type) {
    this.id = id;
    this.type = type;
};

var myCar = new Car(1,"Nissan");

// CAN I DO THIS: (needsWork not a property of object Car)
myCar.needsWork = true;
```

Comment: Note, the Car function in your code is not a class. It is a constructor function. You may call it "pseudo-class".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yea, this is called object augmentation. It is a key feature in JavaScript.

Answer (score 13):

Actually, you have two ways to do that in JavaScript:

1. add a method or property to an instance (this car only)

   ```
   var myCar = new Car(1,"Nissan");
   myCar.needsWork = true;
   ```
2. add a method or property to the car prototype (all cars, even already existing ones)

   ```
   var myCar = new Car(1, "Nissan");
   var biggerCar = new Car(2, "Hummer");
   Car.prototype.needsWork = true;
   alert( myCar.needsWork && biggerCar.needsWork 
           ?  "We need work"
           : "Something wrong here"
   );
   ```

**Reference:**

- [Object.prototype](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype)

Comment: Thanks i was aware of the prototype one i was just wondering if the 1st option was okay. If i could mark 2 answers i would. thanks for the info.

Comment: no prob, upvotes are actually better than accepts. Only upvotes get you tag badges :-)

Comment: P.Floyd I think it's better to attach non-function properties to the object itself (`this.needsWork = true` inside the constructor) rather then to the object's prototype.

Comment: @Šime Vidas sure, it's pretty much the same thing, only I come from a Java background and feel safer if I can actually see the properties I define in the class outline

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**

There is nothing wrong with that.

See Object Augmentation here: http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html