# add new properties to an object in for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do you add more objects to an object on the fly in a for loop in JavaScript

Comment: Yes, it is possible, is this the question?

Comment: Also, note that you are *not* adding "new objects" as your title states, you're just adding new *properties* to an existing object.

Comment: @bfavaretto , that might be true, but the properties are objects as well ;)

Comment: @helmus No, the properties are strings!

Comment: @Hello-World yes it is possible, seems like you got all the answers you needed for this question ?

Comment: @bfavaretto, strings are objects

Comment: @Hello-World Here, see it working: http://jsfiddle.net/zXzkP/

Comment: @helmus Okay, they are. But let's not confuse the OP even further... `:)`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, for any newbies out there, this is the answer:

```
var myOBJ = {};
for (i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    //add new object on each loop
    myOBJ[i+"A"] = i + "loopnumber";
}
```

The final result will be:

```
myOBJ 
{
    0A : "0loopnumber",
    1A : "1loopnumber",
    2A : "2loopnumber",
    3A : "3loopnumber",
    4A : "4loopnumber"
};
```

Comment: So, you already had the answer when you [posted the question](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/11742127/1)?

Comment: seems so,
btw is anywhere a link to the revisions site, or do you have to alter the url

Comment: @Glutamat just click in the last edit's time in the "edited <timestamp>" at the side of the author's signature, it links to the revision story.

Answer (score 1):

**The content below is from the [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326834/can-i-add-a-property-dynamically-in-javascript), and of course, can be accomplished dynamically**

This is called object augmentation. It is a key feature in JavaScript.  Actually, you have two ways to do that in JavaScript:

1. Add a method or property to an instance (this car only)

   var myCar = new Car(1,"Nissan");
   myCar.needsWork = true
2. Add a method or property to the car prototype (all cars, even
   already existing ones)

   var myCar = new Car(1, "Nissan"); 
   var biggerCar = new Car(2, "Hummer"); 
   Car.prototype.needsWork = true;

   alert( myCar.needsWork && biggerCar.needsWork ? "We need work" : "Something wrong here" );

**Reference:**
[Object.prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype)